# How do I calculate the standard deviation of an arbitrary distribution in r?

Tags: r

```
x    Px
134  .5
565  .25
65   .125
563  .125
```

Suppose the above is the data.frame.
Is there a function that I can input it into to compute the standard deviation?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What are each of these values above? Are you defining a discrete distribution? Like this kind of math https://amsi.org.au/ESA_Senior_Years/SeniorTopic4/4c/4c_2content_6.html ?

Comment: While I close this as a dupe, I should second on MrFlick comment. Your question needs clarity. If the dupe doesn't answer your question, ping me and I will cast reopen votes.

Comment: The poster has a finite distribution where each x value has the indicated probability, Px, and wants to calculate the standard deviation of that distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the SD analytically ([more info](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/random-variables-ap/discrete-random-variables/v/variance-and-standard-deviation-of-a-discrete-random-variable)):

[image]

Or numerically:

```
samp = sample(x = x, n = 1e6, replace = TRUE, prob = Px)
sd(samp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sd function from the stats package (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/sd).

Something like this:

```
result = sd(your_data_frame$Px)
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) lm** Assuming input `P` shown in the Note at the end, we can use `lm`

```
fm <- lm(x ~ 1, P, weight = Px)
sqrt(deviance(fm))
## [1] 216.1202
```

or we can replace the last line with:

```
sqrt(nobs(fm) - 1) * sigma(fm)
## [1] 216.1202
```

**2) direct** or do it directly:

```
m <- with(P, sum(x * Px))
with(P, sqrt(sum((x - m)^2 * Px)))
## [1] 216.1202
```

or

```
with(P, sqrt(sum(x^2*Px)-sum(x*Px)^2))
## [1] 216.1202
```

**3)** In the particular example in the question, if we multiply the probabilities by 8 the results are all integer so if we repeat each item that number of times we can simply take the standard deviation of those numbers using `sd` except that `sd` gives the sample standard deviation so we need to correct that to give the population standard deviation.

```
xx <- with(P, rep(x, 8 * Px))
n <- length(xx)
with(P, sqrt((n-1)/n) * sd(xx))
## [1] 216.1202
```

### Note

The input data frame in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "x    Px
134  .5
565  .25
65   .125
563  .125"
P <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```